# "Brush oneself up" is a common phrase?

Tags: idioms, american-english

I once watched some American TV show, and there was a guy, who just woke up, and he said: ***"I need to brush myself up"***. It was clear that he was going to go to the bathroom to take a shower and etc., but I didn't manage to find some examples of using that idiom that way, is that really common phrase? Or was that kind of slang or something? I know only "brush up **on** something".

Comment: You need to give a reference (show name/episode/time marker and a link to the original. Otherwise we're all just going on your guess what they said.

Comment: This doesn't sound natural to me at all. Yes, one _might_ brush one's hair in the morning, but you don't say it like this and you don't refer to the general getting ready in the morning with 'brush'.

Comment: I would give a reference, but I just don't remember the title; it was one of those TLC reality shows. Maybe that guy just was really sleepy... :)

Comment: The idiom 'a wash and brush-up' is very familiar to me, but according to the dictionary it is only used in British English - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brush-up

Comment: @StanDan was it  city or country? Family or young adult? Low class or upper class? Anything else you can say?

Comment: It could be a personal/family/group expression he uses, and it's close to "tidy myself up", "clean myself up", etc, but I have to agree it's not usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm American.  I've never heard that.  I've heard, "I need to brush up" or "I need to go brush up," which means, "I need to brush my teeth."  People often say this in the morning because they often wake with bad breath or with a bad taste in their mouth.

The verb phrase "[brush up](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/brush--up#)" in the above sense is intransitive, not reflexive, so you wouldn't ever say the reflexive pronoun "myself" with it.

If you click that link and scroll down to "brush up," you will see it *is* transitive when it refers to refreshing your knowledge about something and so can take an object like "myself," albeit it requires the addition of the preposition "on" if you do.  Without "on,: transitively, the object is what's being reviewed (e.g., "I'm going to brush up my writing skills," albeit "I'm going to brush up on my writing skills" is also correct.). So, my point is, you're right about that.  Saying "myself" with "brush up" denotes refreshing your knowledge or memory by reviewing related materials.

Comment: I speak AmE. All my life I've heard/used *brush up on (something)*. I've never used the phrase without the *on*. Could this be a dialect thing or something newish?

Answer (score 0):

I'm American. I have never heard someone use that particular phrase. I've heard, "I need to clean myself up," or "I need to wash myself up," to convey that meaning.

I have only ever heard someone say they're going to brush themselves up *on* something, which has an entirely different meaning: to refamiliarize themselves with material on a certain topic.